# csv file not read correctly (almost half of the rows are removed)

Tags: r, csv, readr

I want to read in a csv file with R. It has a semicolon as the separator and uses double quotes as quotes.

However, the file has some problematic cells (e.g. some have one double quote in text cells or an semicolon in the text) which leads to R not reading the file in correctly.

Since I can't upload a file, here's how the csv looks like when opened with a text editor:

```
"X1";"X2";"X3"
"1";"0";"test"
"37129";"11746; weird";"weird "thing""
"27929";"1";"xyz Limited"
```

Row 1 contain the headlines. In row 3 you can see that the X2 value has a semicolon after "11746" and the X3 value has an additional double quote before "thing".

So when reading this file in with `readr::read_csv2(file = my_file.csv)` in this small example it looks ok, but it actually isn't (note that my real file has 13k rows). For example, we'd expect to see double quotes before and after "thing".

When I use `readr::read_csv2(file = my_file.csv, quote = "")` instead, row 2's values are shifted due to the semicolon.

Any idea, how I could solve this issue?

The expected output would be:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     X1 X2           X3             
  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>          
1     1 0            "test"         
2 37129 11746; weird "\"weird thing\""
3 27929 1            "xyz Limited"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not standards-compliant semi-colon-CSV. The `"thing"` quotes should be doubled to be escaped, as in `"37129";"11746; weird";"weird ""thing"""`. Whatever is creating that file is not adhering to the standard.

We can try to use regex to parse the contents, changing the embedded `"` quotes to double `""` (and not changing the enclosing `"`s), perhaps this:

```bash
## on the shell, not in R
$ sed -E 's/([^;])"([^;])/\1""\2/g' quux.csv > newquux.csv
```

```r
## in R
read.csv2("newquux.csv")
#      X1           X2            X3
# 1     1            0          test
# 2 37129 11746; weird weird "thing"
# 3 27929            1   xyz Limited
```

One might be tempted to do this in R instead, which is generally fine. However, if the csv file is huge, then this will cause an unnecessary growth in the R's memory consumption ... again, only an issue if your file is huge.

```r
read.csv2(
  text = gsub('(?<=[^;])"(?=[^;])', '""',
              readLines("quux.csv"), perl = TRUE))
#      X1           X2            X3
# 1     1            0          test
# 2 37129 11746; weird weird "thing"
# 3 27929            1   xyz Limited
```

Both of the above work just as well with `readr::read_csv2`:

```r
readr::read_csv2("newquux.csv")
readr::read_csv2(
  I(gsub('(?<=[^;])"(?=[^;])', '""',
         readLines("quux.csv"), perl = TRUE)))
```

(The `I(..)` is necessary here since otherwise it opts to look for a file named `"X1";"X2";"X3"`.)

Comment: Whatever miracle is doing its magic here, it works (at first glance...obviously I need a bit of time to scan through my 13k rows file to see if it has some side effects). In any case, thanks for that solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to speficy `"` as the quote character, I got what I think you want with this:

```
read.table("test.csv", sep=";", quote = "\"", header= FALSE)
```

However, the quotes are removed as they are quoting characters, do you want to keep them as well?

The output:

```
     V1           V2          V3
1    X1           X2          X3
2     1            0        test
3 37129 11746; weird weird thing
4 27929            1 xyz Limited
```

Comment: This is dropping the quotes around `"thing"`.

Comment: Ohh sorry I did not see that! I see you already posted a solution to take care of that. I would just keep the quoting characters and actual quotes that I want to keep as different characters, but I assume the OP has no control over it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-standard file format but we can read it in using readLines and then replace the delimiting quotes with some other character not in the file -- here we use a single quote as that character.

```
"my_file.csv" |>
  readLines() |>
  gsub('^"|"$', "'", x = _) |>  # replace " with ' at start & end of each line
  gsub('";"', "';'", x = _) |>  # replace ";" with ';'
  read.csv2(text = _, quote = "'")
##      X1           X2            X3
## 1     1            0          test
## 2 37129 11746; weird weird "thing"
## 3 27929            1   xyz Limited
```

We can use this code to check which characters are in the file. Any character not listed can be used as the new quote character.

```
"my_file.csv" |>
  readLines() |>
  strsplit("") |>
  unlist() |>
  table() |>
  names() |>
  cat("\n")
## " ; 0 1 2 3 4 6 7 9 d e g h i L m n r s t w x X y z
```

or we can use this code to check whether a particular character, here single quote, appears in the file.  If 1 is returned as it does with the example input in the question then that character does not appear and otherwise it does.

```
max(count.fields("my_file.csv", sep = "'", quote = ""))
## [1] 1
```